# OWIN Bearer Token Authentication

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, owin, asp.net-identity-2, bearer-token

I have some questions related to Bearer Token. In Owin you can protect a ticket `Protect(ticket)` like this:

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Startup.OAuthServerOptions.AuthenticationType);

identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));

 Dictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 properties.Add("UserId", user.Id);
 properties.Add("UserName", user.UserName);
 properties.Add("Role", "user");

 AuthenticationProperties properties = new AuthenticationProperties(properties);

 AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);


 DateTime currentUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

 DateTime expireUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(24));

 ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
 ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = expireUtc;


 string token = OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket)
```

Now the token will be something like this:

`nqak-9R6U64Owsm_lqn_mJzKc_Djd8iVnIw0EX77v5x2rybhf4m_zg_UnrsoO5BxDZQl0HWrSvvd4efa4ChNSf5rAGhd13aOXZlvwOJOZ5v_9bhRCq8A7tqHyiM6DqVVOyYs3lh2SU-wU1m85HH2IcYDtdTY3ijaKZ_QnP1nsqO5LRnnEL4upbETPW9zqWIZzZBX7_Y2cXi2v0K7WnlRor3gFKIZlU9J-NfidRpWXqq5744NfWWHalYADGS7eUWyuxPJCj9ykHYzaXFksJEXBw`

My questions:

- How this token is generated/encrypted?
- Are there any chances that somebody can try to mess'up with the token and add some custom claims to it?

Example:

If you have the token string you can do this:

```
AuthenticationTicket ticket = OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(token);
```

Now you can add custom claims to it. For example if there is a `role` claim with value `user` then you can modify that claim and add `admin` then re encode the ticket and you get a token that has admin role.

I actually din some tests, encoded a token on a server and then try to modify it on another system but I couldn't `Unprotect` it. Therefore I am thinking maybe the ticket is encrypted/decrypted using the machine key on which was originally created. However if I try to `Unprotect` it from the same machine it works. I can decrypt it and modify it.

Can somebody explain this process please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> How this token is generated/encrypted?

The data protection provider can be set using the `SetDataProtectionProvider` extension method on the `IAppBuilder` object. When this is not done, the data protection provider of the host is used. In case of IIS + ASP.NET, this is `MachineKeyDataProtector` in the assembly `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`. For self-hosting, this will be DPAPI. Basically, the token is encrypted and then MACed and that is what `Protect()` is all about.

> Are there any chances that somebody can try to mess'up with the token and add some custom > claims to it?

No. This is not possible. Token protected in a machine cannot be unprotected somewhere else. An exception to that will be the case of a web farm where you have multiple machines. One machine can protect and if the subsequent request goes to some other machine, that machine should have the ability to unprotect. With DPAPI, this is not possible. With `MachineKeyDataProtector`, this is possible by having the same `machineKey` section in all the machines. But then if you are concerned about some MITM being able to do this, then no, it is not possible.

Comment: I thought the same when I tested it but wanted to be sure I'm on the right path! Thank your for clarification.

Comment: What if man in the middle gets the `Facebook` token, can he impersonate a user?

Comment: Further reading on default data protection providers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthauthorizationserveroptions.accesstokenformat(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Here is a [tool](https://github.com/Legends/BearerTokenDeserializer) that decrypts OAuth 2.0 Bearer tokens using `MachineKeyDataProtector`

Comment: @Legends it's worth mentioning that tool requires the secret / machine key.  http://jwt.io does the same.

Comment: @RandomUs1r You can't decode if you don't have the key.